# Get Scale Set (VMSS) instances info vie Azure Resource Graph

Tags: azure, kql, azure-resource-graph

I want to get vm/instance information on instances running under a VMSS using Azure resource-graph.

I'm trying to get info similar to what is returned from querying `resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'`. i.e the instance name, AZ, id etc'.

My issue that `'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'` does not return instances under a VMSS, and the data returned from `resources | where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets'` doesn't seem to contain information that will allow to query the instances themselves.